# reliability of spring integration esb

Tags: esb, spring-integration

How the reliability of message transmission be protected in the spring intergration?
For example, the server crashed when messages transforming in the router, or messages were processed failed in splitter and transformer?
How the mechanism handles those situation？Is there any references or documents?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Also, if your entry point is a channel adapter or gateway that supports transactions (e.g. JMS, AMQP, JDBC, JPA,..) and you use default channels, the entire flow will take place within the scope of that transaction, as the transaction context is bound to the thread. If you add any buffering channels or a downstream aggregator, then you would want to consider what Gary mentioned so that you are actually completing the initial transaction by handing responsibility to another reliable resource (as opposed to leaving a Message in an in-memory Map and then committing, for example).

Hope that makes sense.

Shameless plug: there's a good overview of transactions within the Spring Integration in Action book, available now through MEAP: http://manning.com/fisher/

Regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

By default, messages are held in memory but you can declare channels to be persistent, as needed. Persistent channels use JMS, AMQP (rabbit), or a message store. A number of message stores are provided, including JDBC, MongoDB, Redis, or you can construct one that uses a technology of your choice.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/